# INSERT data from database into another database, running on different hosts

Tags: sql, drupal, triggers, mariadb, civicrm

I'm facing the following problem:

I have two MariaDB databases, running on two different hosts. Both of them are used to run two different websites, each of them having Drupal and CiviCRM installed and running.

Some of the data stored in the contacts table of CiviCRM from website 1 needs to be kept in sync with these same contacts on website 2.
Keeping in sync means : inserting new contacts, and updating existing contacts.

I was wondering if this coud be done via trigger?
I know I can activate remote sql on my cPanel, as I use this to work with Mysql Workbench or similar software.

Any ideas? Would a trigger work? Do I rather need to write some code in another language than SQL?

Comment: Hi Steve. Please supply the SQL you have tried so far so we can help.

Comment: You would probably be better off if they referenced the _same_ database.

Comment: Since your question about data synch seems primarily about CiviCRM you might get useful advice by asking at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the kind of sql I'd like to use: CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON HOST1.DATABASE.contacts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO HOST2.DATABASE.contacts_audit
   ( contact_id,
     updated_date,
     updated_by)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.contact_id,
     SYSDATE(),
     );

END; //

Comment: since it is two different websites, there are two different hosts - they cannot be in the same DB

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple databases at the same time for your Drupal to connect to in your settings.php:

```
$databases = [
    'HOST1.DATABASE' => [
        'default' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'prefix' => '',
            'database' => 'contacts',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
         ],
    ],
    'HOST2.DATABASE' => [
        'default' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'prefix' => '',
            'database' => 'contacts_audit',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
         ],
    ],
];
```

After this you can define in the `getConnection()` method, which key of the `$database` array you want to connect.

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('HOST1.DATABASE')
    ->query('CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON contacts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN')
    ->execute();
```

and

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('HOST2.DATABASE')
    ->query('INSERT INTO contacts_audit ( contact_id, updated_date, updated_by) VALUES ( NEW.contact_id, SYSDATE(), ); END;')
    ->execute();
```

(If you leave the parameter of `getConnection()` empty, it would connect to the database on `$databases['default']` key. Also, you can use `setActiveConnection()` if you want to work more with the database, which as its name says, sets the active connection to the desired key of `$databases`)

Hope this helps some way.